# Verify final result code for completed build operation

Tags: jenkins, xcode9, jenkins-cli

All,

I am using Jenkins for CL, Recently we updated to Xcode 9, from then we are getting below issue.

How can we resolve it, In another machine by reducing the folder structure it worked, How can we solve it without changing the folder structure?

**Build operation failed without specifying any errors. Individual build tasks may have failed for unknown reasons.
One possible cause is if there are too many (possibly zombie) processes; in this case, rebooting may fix the problem.
Some individual build task failures (up to 12) may be listed below.**

Answer (score 0):

It's an OS issue, there's no known workarounds for this.

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48525938/736384