# Zombie: Archiving Failed using Integration Menu

Tags: ios, xcode, zombie-process, archiving

When I tried to archiving the project directly using Xcode menu (**Product - Archive**), it works well. But when I tried to execute it from the Integration menu (bot), I got this error:

> Build operation failed without specifying any errors. Individual build
>   tasks may have failed for unknown reasons. One possible cause is if
>   there are too many (possibly zombie) processes; in this case,
>   rebooting may fix the problem. Some individual build task failures (up
>   to 12) may be listed below.

What happen? I couldn't find any error messages and completely have no clue on what's going on. I have tried to reboot the macmini and also revert the changes but it still.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## UPDATE (Edit 3)

**The issue has been fixed on [Xcode 11, from beta 3](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_6_release_notes)**:

> - Xcode uses response files by default to pass input files to the Swift compiler. To turn this behavior off, set USE_SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE to NO.
> - You can use an unlimited number of Swift files in a target. (35879960)

## Old answer

I've only seen this error arising when the total of files (notice all their respective absolute paths count) exceed the command line length limit ([looks like it's imposed by the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355351/736384), currently 262144 bytes on my rMBP). [It's a known issue.](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-build-dev/Week-of-Mon-20170814/001065.html)

To fix this (AFAIK), you have 2 options:

- **Fast (short term)**: Put your project on a shorter path on the server (like moving the project from `/Users/mrjimoy_05_server/myprojects/mycoolproject/` to `/p/mycoolproject`)
- **Better (long term)**: While the first solution might work, for now, you'll probably reach the same point where you're now in the near future. So a better solution is to modularize your app (separate it into frameworks/projects). Since every module will get built separately, it'll be much harder to reach the limit and get this error again.

I hope it helps.

PD: Looks like the error thrown by the **New Build System** is:

> unable to spawn process (File exists)

**Edit 1**

The error thrown by the **New Build System** on Xcode 10 now is:

> unable to spawn process (Argument list too long)

**Edit 2**

The [Swift team have solved this issue](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-compilation-reaching-arg-max-limit-causing-xcode-build-failure/6494/6), but it also needs [some work from the Xcode team](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-compilation-reaching-arg-max-limit-causing-xcode-build-failure/6494/10), which hasn't been done yet on the latest released Xcode version (10.2)

Comment: Hi @Luis Arcorbe, thank you for your suggestion. But how to make sure the path? It works on common Xcode build, but doesn't work on the Integration Bot, which then I couldn't determine the file location.

Comment: Ah ic, it works now, I am using your Fast solution for now and will implement the rest soon. Thank you! :)

Comment: I am facing this issue in objc project, do you have any solutions?

Comment: @ooops AFAIK this only happens with Swift files. Can you elaborate? What exact error? Project config?

Comment: @LuisAscorbe Error is `unable to spawn process (Argument list too long)`, all script phase show this error. Config may changed I don't know much. I am using Xcode 11 Beta 7.

Comment: @ooops are you using CocoaPods? How many dependencies you have?

Comment: I am new to `XCode`. How/where do I set `USE_SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE`

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. But if you *really* need to: got to Build Settings and add USE_SWIFT_RESPONSE_FILE with the + button at top.